# In Tor Browser, I connect to the exact same entry node all the time, unable to change it

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I've been using Tor Browser Bundle for a long time, and it used to always pick a different circuit for every site, including changing the entry node for every circuit but then it just suddenly became static with the entry nodes. The version didn't change, it was the latest one and behaved "normally" (as it always used to) before starting doing this.

My entry node always stays the same, and doesn't change, even when connecting to different sites, even after using New Tor Circuit for this Site. Even after restarting Tor Browser, the entry node is still the same, for every circuit.

The circuits themselves do change and are different each time, just the entry node always stays the same.
It's driving me crazy. I've even reinstalled Tor Browser multiple times, that actually did change the entry node I was connecting to, but again, it was the same one for every circuit and every site.

I don't really see a security risk in this but it seems suspicious since there was no update before this started.

Why is this? Is this normal Tor behavior now?